# JAVA DES in PHP

Tags: java, php

I can't get the same result of encrypted text in JAVA from my php script.
This is my php code (client side - my side):

```
$input = 'my text to be encrypted';
$key = 'my key';

$size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_DES, 'ecb');
$input = pkcs5_pad($input, $size);
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', 'ecb', '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
print base64_encode($data);

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
```

This is The base JAVA code (Server side):

```
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");
Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
// Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
return  new String(Base64Utils.encode(enc));
```

I know there's a padding problem in php that makes the difference in my result.
Can't find why.

Comment: FYI, you really should not use ECB mode, as it makes the encryption quite trivial to break. Use CBC mode with an IV. (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IV has to match what java is using too. 
Since you're just generating a random one, it'll never match.
(The mcrypt_create_iv() function )

Find out what (if any) java uses.

Comment: you can get it with `getIV()` method.

Comment: JAVA returns null, When i'm trying to remove IV from php I'm getting a warning - "Attempt to use an empty IV" and the result is the same from php.