# Encryption with PHP, decryption with Java : IOException: data not block size aligned

Tags: php, android, image, encryption

I'm using PHP encryption of data and than I'm decrypting the data (images) in my Android application,but sometimes it's throwin me an IOException and I'm not really sure how to fix that.When I'm encrypting an PNG image file,it's ok,there is no exception thrown and my app can load the image in list view.But when I'm encrypting a jpg file it's throwing me this exception :

```
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254): java.io.IOException: data not block size aligned
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:97)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:152)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:183)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:346)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:515)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at com.custom.lazylist.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:105)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at com.custom.lazylist.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:75)
08-04 06:36:54.734: WARN/System.err(254):     at com.custom.lazylist.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:228)
```

I read over the internet that it's the problem is probably using NoPadding at encrypting and decrypting code.Here is the Java code and PHP code :

**JAVA**

```
    try {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("01234567890abcde".getBytes(), "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("fedcba9876543210".getBytes());
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    AssetManager is = this.getAssets();
    InputStream fis = is.open("card2_encrypted.jpg");

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    FileOutputStream fos  = new FileOutputStream(
               new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "card2_decrypted.jpg"));




    byte[] b = new byte[8];
    int i;

    while ((i = cis.read(b)) != -1) {
      fos.write(b, 0, i);
    }
    fos.flush(); fos.close();
    cis.close(); fis.close();   

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.fillInStackTrace();
        Log.v("Error","Error "+e);
    }
    }
```

and the **PHP** code :

```
<?php
    $secret_key   = "01234567890abcde";
    $iv           = "fedcba9876543210";
    $infile       = "ss1.jpg";
    $outfile      = "ss1_encrypted.jpg";

    $crypttext = file_get_contents($infile);
    $plaintext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
    $secret_key, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($plaintext));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . ($outfile));
    echo $plaintext;
?>
```

So my quesion is how can I fix that stuff with padding in php and java code,so I can load my images in my app.Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217920/java-des-in-php and http://tsrini.blogspot.com/2009/12/encrypt-in-java-and-decrypt-in-php.html may these helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify padding at the encryption end, and the same padding at the decryption end so the padding can be removed.  You are using a block cypher, AES, so all messages need to be padded to a mutliple of the block size.  Hence your error message "data not block size aligned".

Check what paddings are available at both ends and pick one that they both support.  PKCS#5 is a common padding convention which is likely to be available on both systems.  I do not know PHP, but in Java you would need:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Comment: As a matter of fact I know how to do it in Java,but Php is my problem.

Comment: And the strange thing is that when I'm decrypting an png file,there is no exception,but when I'm tryin to decrypt a jpg file, it's throw me the exception.

Comment: @psychenaut: Sorry I can't help with PHP.  As to the .png file, it may be that the file happens to be an exact number of blocks.  Have you tried different sized .png files?

Comment: Yes,i tried with 5 different images and there is no exception,only with jpegs